# How to reverse OneHotEncoderEstimator transformation in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

So In Spark you can you `OneHotEncoderEstimator` to one-hot encode a column like this

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoderEstimator

val oneHotEncoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator()
  .setInputCols(Array(...))
  .setOutputCols(...))
  .setDropLast(false)
oneHotEncoder.fit(...)
```

But how would you do the inverse operation? i.e. the equivalent of sklearn `inverse_transform`

[image]